# caching db table at a particular time?

Tags: java, database, caching

I have to cache some db records some time period.

For example i am assuming huge traffic on my website at 4 pm today.I will cache the login table at around 3.50.Because i know that users will come at this time.

How can i go about it  in java?I am thinking is running a thread at specific interval and then
running it at every 1 hr to check if i need something to be cached

Is the thread guaranteed to run?

```
class Mthread extends Thread{

 run(){
  //update cache
 }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you may take a look on java Cron. I guess this should solve your problem.
http://www.sauronsoftware.it/projects/cron4j/

Cron jobs are used to trigger some action at particular time  and is highly configurable like you can configure it to work daily at 3:50 PM.
Hopefully it should solve your problem

Answer (score 0):

You can implement your run() method using a while loop that loops indefinitely.  At the end of every iteration of the loop, calculate the number of milliseconds for your thread to sleep until the next update time (perhaps set a maximum sleep time if you want it to wake up periodically).  The thread is guaranteed to run when you want it to, provided the following:

1. You tell it exactly how long it needs to sleep or wait until the next cache update time.
2. Your thread doesn't get interrupted before you want it to.
3. No exceptions cause your thread's run() method to return prematurely.
4. Your thread doesn't cause some weird error, like an OutOfMemoryError, to occur.